# mysql_real_escape_string returns empty/blank inside a DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, string, mysql-real-escape-string, ezsql

I have a problem with mysql_real_escape_string. I use ezSQL to connect with MySQL.

**Problem:**

> mysql_real_escape_string($username) and mysql_real_escape_string($password) turns empty.

**Code:**

```
$row = $db->get_row("SELECT firstname, secondname, id FROM users WHERE login='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");
```

**Work-around:**

Putting mysql_real_escape_string BEFORE or inside $row makes the value empty. Putting mysql_real_escape_string AFTER $row makes it work. Hence; Have another $db in front of the exsisting $row:

```
$row2 = $db->get_row("SELECT firstname, secondname, id FROM users");
$row = $db->get_row("SELECT firstname, secondname, id FROM users WHERE login='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");
```

**Question:**

How can i properly fix this?

Comment: ezsql has its own escape method you should be using

Comment: Warning

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used

You shouldn't use any mysql_* functions.

http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Solution -> upgrade to mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ezsql has its own escape method you should be using –  [Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon)

Thank you, this solved my question! I have updated my code to:

```
$password = $db->escape($_POST['password']);
$username = $db->escape($_POST['username']);
$row = $db->get_row("SELECT firstname, secondname, id FROM users WHERE login='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
```

I will work towards upgrading to MySQLi later. I know that ezSQL also offers a MySQLi component. Thanks for your suggestions [Destruction](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3378288/destruction), [meda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880431/meda) and [Christophe Ferreboeuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2660794/christophe-ferreboeuf)!

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use mysqli or pdo as mysql functions are [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php contains a good example that you can adapt to you case. You set first a connection the way you do with mysql, then you prepare the query, you bind the parameters that will be automatically escaped and then you can fetch.